# Cant find `uses-sdk` in Android Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I started to learn android using Android Studio 0.8.2 and I started a new project with the minimum API as 15. But in my *AndroidManifest.xml*, doesn't appear the `uses-sdk` tag.

Do I have to insert it by myself? Shouldn't the project create it? Or is Android Studio different and is no longer necessary to insert this in manifest, only in the *build.gradle*?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: By the way, targetSdk is for uses-sdk, not minSdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default template in Android Studio is ready to work with gradle.
If you check your project you will find a build.gradle file inside your app module.
Here you can find something like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxxx'
        minSdkVersion 15          //your minSdk
        targetSdkVersion XX       //your targetVersion
        versionCode 0
        versionName '0.1.0'
    }
```

Gradle building the project **will override** the *uses-sdk* tag in your Manifest.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, add it manually.

Android studio uses build.gradle to build the project so it doesn't care about the manifest, and that's probably why it doesn't insert it in it. However, it is important to have it in the manifest, for when you publish the app, as Google play uses this for filtering the devices.

Comment: No, this isn't what I am trying to say. I am only talking about uses-sdk. If you don't set the permission properly to use the camera, the app will fail at runtime when you try to access the camera, though it will build and rest of app will run. You need to understand the difference between buildtime and runtime. Gradle is for building, manifest is for runtime. Sometimes, it may build but not run (for example, if you forget to declare an activity in manifest, it will build but this activity will not run). Additionally, the manifest is also used for Google play filtering.